# Ext js: submit disabled fields as blank

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a form where depending on the value in field 'a', an optional field 'b' is enabled/disabled.

If data is submitted with an a-value where b is enabled, the database contains a value for b as well.
The problem is that when the user then edits that record, selecting an a-value where b is disabled, I want the submit to submit a 'blank' value (empty string) in order to clean the database record.

(please do no argue that the backend should be intelligent enough to discard the b value in that case ... since that is out of my control)

I tried to enable the b-field and setting it to '' before submitting, but the b-field still isn't submitted. (using the on-beforeaction-submit)

I even tried to fiddle with other parameters (like originalValue) to make sure the b-field is dirty. I even tested with a random value (for the setValue call), just to make sure it's not a 'blank' field behaviour. But even when setting 'X' , the value isn't submitted. Nothing helps.

I'm sure i'm overlooking something really trivial, but I can't figure it out.
So after spending hours to find out reading through posts and testing, I give up and address to the community.

Thx,
C.

```
form.on('beforeaction', function(form, action) {
  if (action.type == 'submit') {
    //clean disabled fields before submitting
    if (item!='general') {
      var escid = Ext.getCmp('spcway-' + item + '-form-escid');
      if (escid.disabled) {escid.enable(); escid.originalValue='abc'; escid.allowBlank=true; escid.setValue(''); escid.allowBlank=false}
      if (item!='status') {
        var escoption = Ext.getCmp('spcway-' + item + '-form-escoption');
        if (escoption.disabled) {escoption.enable(); escoption.originalValue='abc'; escoption.setValue('')}
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
});
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: My question is how to make sure fields which were disabled at the moment of clicking the save/submit button, will also sumbit the disabled Fields. I manage to enable the and manage to get them dirty just before the actual submit call. But this doesn't submit the fields. It's like the js console still believes these fields which were disabled at the start of the button click, still do not need to be submitted. There fields do not appear in the data, no matter what I try. Even setting them to an arbitrary value doesn't trigger to be included in the post data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the field to readonly instead of disabled, then it will still be posted with the form data but will not be editable for the user.

```html
<label>disabled</label>
  <input type="text" disabled/>
  <label>readonly</label>
  <input type="text" readonly/>
```

Comment: The trouble with readonly is that it's not so obvious to the used he shouldn't use the field. But I'll give it a try just to see if is makes it to the data at post

Comment: I Just tested, and the fields are added to the post data now. I don't really like it too much for the reason stated above, but untill someone comes up with a better solution, I'll use this and add a dynamic tooltip with 'Field not applicable' or so.

Comment: you can change the css for a readonly field input:read-only { 
    background-color: grey;
}

Comment: Thanks Kurt. This then _completely_ solves the issue, since the behaviour would be similar to a disabled field. One difference I noticed while testing: hitting backspace in a selected readonly field results in the browser going to the previous page (depends on browser settings), whereas a disabled field can not be selected and thus not result in this mistake. Thanks to you all

Comment: No problem. Thats strange, I have a feeling that the field is not selected since there can be no focus on it but perhaps the content is highlighted, then back space would trigger the history. But if theres no cursor on the field its not selected.